# issues of inserting pictures in Jupyter notebook in Mac OS

Tags: jupyter-notebook

it can't display successfully when I try to insert pictures in Juypter notebook. All I can see is just the question mark where the picture should display. And the feedback from the console starts with "404 GET".

First, from the local computer, it only works for a relative dir situation which means you have to put the picture in the exactly current dir of Jupyter notebook and must use the relative dir way;
Second, from the website, it doesn't work at all, even if you use other methods such as 'from IPython.core.display import HTML ' with 'display' method and 'img src' method.

```
![im_label](wx_logo.png)
```

this code works when you put 'wx_logo.png' in the exactly current dir of Jupyter notebook. But

```
![im_label](nbdir/wx_logo.png)
```

doesn't work even if nbdir is the exactly current dir of Jupyter notebook.

I wonder maybe there are some settings needed for my Jupyter notebook or Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you use...

```
![im_label](nbdir/wx_logo.png)
```

then, `nbdir` shouldn't be the current dir of your notebook, but another dir just at the same level of the .ipynb.

```
/
+-- yourNotebook.ipynb
+-- nbdir
    +-- wx_logo.png
```

That should work.

Comment: what I mean is 'wx_logo.png' and 'yourNotebook.ipynb' share the same dir, which is like
```nbdir/yourNotebook.ipynb<br>

    nbdir/wx_logo.png
```

Comment: Well, what I mean is `nbdir=/Users/wenxin`, which makes `nbdir/wx_logo.png` a fully path of the picture file.
I know what you mean. But I don't think it's a path issue. Thank you all the same.